# Set targeted audience for calendar using workflow

Tags: 2010, list, calendar, audience-targeting

As per the title.

I am to set a target audience on a calendar.  I am restricted to an OOB simple solution.  I want users to only see the items they have added.  I don't want them to see other items added by other users.  I want all items to be viewable to a specific audience.

I have enabled targeted audience on the calendar list.  My first test was to see if I could see all added, but for my test users to only see their own.  My test users seen all.  FAIL.

I have noticed that when I view the calendar event, the target audience field appears blank.  But when I go to edit the item, my sharepoint group appears?

Is this a bug?

I want to set a valid target audience of SharePoint group, only allow users to see their content, but allow the group to see all content.  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target audiences is primarily used for content roll-ups, it is NOT used for permissions or restrictions.

Two quick options:

1) An onCreate SharePoint designer workflow that sets permissions to (a) user who created the item and (b) custom admin group you setup

2) In "Advanced Settings" under your Calendar settings, you can set "Read" permissions to "Read items that were created by the user", then grant your admins a high enough permission to the calendar that they can see all of them, e.g. "Full Control"

Comment: Thanks, I can set permissions in workflow you're saying?  I can't see that in the actions in SPD2010?

Comment: you may have to use an "Impersonation Step" in the workflow, then I think it is called "Replace Permissions"

Comment: Ok- I think you've nearly got me there.  The credentials are based on my SharePoint permissions or current list permissions?  Any ideas?

Comment: My recommendation is that you grant "Read" rights for the Calendar to All Users (Everyone), when you run the workflow, you will be "breaking" permissions at an item level.  Each item will have two permissions: probably (1) user who created the item has "Edit" and (2) admin group has "Read".  The workflow itself will run as the person who publishes the workflow (i.e. You).

Comment: Ok, but if everyone initially has read access, how can I trigger the workflow to run if I can't add an item anyway?  Assuming I'm user X, I don't have access to add....

Comment: Ah, good catch! give everyone (who should be able to add events) contribute access by default

Comment: You've been most helpful.  I appreciate it.  If I run into issues, hopefully I can come back to this thread?  Marked answer ;-)